# Split array into smaller unequal-sized arrays dependend on array-column values

Tags: arrays, matlab, split

I'm quite new to MatLab and this problem really drives me insane:

I have a huge array of 2 column and about 31,000 rows. One of the two columns depicts a spatial coordinate on a grid the other one a dependent parameter. What I want to do is the following:

I. I need to split the array into smaller parts defined by the spatial column; let's say the spatial coordinate are ranging from 0 to 500 - I now want arrays that give me the two column values for spatial coordinate 0-10, then 10-20 and so on. This would result in 50 arrays of unequal size that cover a spatial range from 0 to 500.

II. Secondly, I would need to calculate the average values of the resulting columns of every single array so that I obtain per array one 2-dimensional point.

III. Thirdly, I could plot these points and I would be super happy.

Sadly, I'm super confused since I miserably fail at step I. - Maybe there is even an easier way than to split the giant array in so many small arrays - who knows..

I would be really really happy for any suggestion.

Thank you,

Arne

Comment: Please paste here some exemplary MATLAB code.

Comment: thanks it worked out great - cant vote you up because of my account reputation but thumbs up :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you wish a data structure of array of different size you will need to place them in a cell array so you could try something like this:

```
res = arrayfun(@(x)arr(arr(:,1)==x,:), unique(arr(:,1)), 'UniformOutput', 0);
```

The previous code return a cell array with the array splitted according its first column with `@(x)arr(arr(:,1)==x,:)` you are doing a function on **x** and `arrayfun(function, ..., 'UniformOutput', 0)` applies function to each element in the following arguments (taken a single value of each argument to evaluate the function) but you must notice that arr must be numeric so if not you should map your values to numeric values or use another way to select this values.

In the same way you could do

```
uo = 'UniformOutput';
res = arrayfun(@(x){arr(arr(:,1)==x,:), mean(arr(arr(:,1)==x,2))), unique(arr(:,1)), uo, 0);
```

You will probably want to flat the returning value, check the function `cat`, you could do:

```
res = cat(1,res{:})
```

Plot your data depends on their format, so I can't help if i don't know how the data are, but you could try to plot inside a loop over your 'res' variable or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Step I indeed comes with some difficulties. Once these are solved, I guess steps II and III can easily be solved. Let me make some suggestions for step I:

You first define the maximum value (`maxValue = 500;`) and the step size (`stepSize = 10;`). Now it is possible to iterate through all steps and create your new vectors.

```
for k=1:maxValue/stepSize
    ...
end
```

As every resulting array will have different dimensions, I suggest you save the vectors in a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/matlab/ref/cell.html?refresh=true):

```
Y = cell(maxValue/stepSize,1);
```

Use the [find](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function to find the rows of the entries for each matrix. At each step `k`, the range of values of interest will be `(k-1)*stepSize` to `k*stepSize`.

```
row = find( (k-1)*stepSize <= X(:,1) & X(:,1) < k*stepSize );
```

You can now create the matrix for a step`k` by

```
Y{k,1} = X(row,:);
```

Putting everything together you should be able to create the cell array `Y` containing your matrices and continue with the other tasks. You could also save the average of each value range in a second column of the cell array `Y`:

```
Y{k,2} = mean( Y{k,1}(:,2) );
```

I hope this helps you with your task. Note that these are only suggestions and there may be different (maybe more appropriate) ways to handle this.